# Devise - undefined method: username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Learning rails, using the treehouse videos to build a simple social network.

After making the following changes to add additional fields to devise:

new.html.erb (New Registration)

```
  <div><%= f.label :username %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :username %></div>
```

devise_create_users migration file

```
  t.string :username,
  t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
```

I use rake db:reset and then rake db:migrate to attempt to initiate the database changes however the schema remains the same, without the username field.

I get the error: undefined method `username' for #

On the line:

```
<%= f.text_field :username %></div>
```

Any help really appreciated, not sure if this is a version related issue or whether treehouse has left out some information.

Thanks!

Devise Migration:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :username,
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

schema:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140720141519) do

  create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["article_id"], name: "index_comments_on_article_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: Any errors you got while running `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: @Pavan - Nope, db:migrate returns nothing - db:reset returns the build of the table however the users row creates no username column :(

Comment: If you are doing rake db:reset then you don't need rake db:migrate(if you didn't add a new migration). Can you post all of your devise_create_users migration file and also your schema.rb

Comment: @Mandeep Thanks for the info - I've added the schema and migration to the main post!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your migration. Comma is not needed at the end of line

```
t.string :username,
```

As I see there is no `username` column in `users` table in your schema. Just remove the comma and recreate you database with `$ rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate`.

Comment: I removed the comma and it still isn't added to the schema after a db:reset :(

Comment: You should regenerate your `schema.rb` file. Try to run `$ rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Got it working! However, the form isn't actually registering to the database, I'm getting a nil, any idea why?

Comment: To find the problem you should add your controller and view code.